# How do I combine multiple third party tags (javascripts) into one

Tags: javascript, tags

How do I combine multiple third party tags (javascripts) like Google Analytics and other various third party service provider javascript tags into one hosted on our server ?

The idea is to set "our" tag to customers sites while allowing us to remotely update the combination of those scripts without having to access their servers in the future.

What mechanism is the simplest to allow loading these third party scripts remotely after having "our" tag loaded?

Comment: Download them and copy/paste into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe that calls a specific page like

```
<iframe src="example.com/userID">
```

The server should return the correct html.

I will then be filled with the analytics utilities. 
You will have a hard time accessing the parent DOM element though.