# Best way to bundle multiple third-party javascript libraries into one with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webpack, bundle

I was following the webpack tutorial and as much as I understood it, to bundle everything into one module it requires the scripts to use `require('./xyz')`

Instead until now, I used to write everything in separate scripts and load all the scripts in HTML with multiple script tags. I don't think changing every script is possible now. So is there any way to bundle everything into one module and use it?

PS: something like this : [similar SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412793/how-do-i-combine-multiple-third-party-tags-javascripts-into-one)

Another thing I wanted to ask, as title says, How to bundle third party libraries like `angularjs`, `jquery`, `bootstrap`, `ui-router` and so on? (with no common connection with each other)? I tried giving an array as `entry` to the webpack and it produced a large 4MB JS plus it didn't even work. What is the better way to do it?

Comment: Just import the external libarys in your file which you set as Entrypoint an webpack will bundle them

Comment: So writing just `require('angular')` would be sufficient enough?

Comment: Yes, you should read this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: But I said already I can't change JS files now.

Comment: "But I said already I can't change JS files now." What does it mean? you cant modify your index.js which is your entrypoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [explicit vendor chunk](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#explicit-vendor-chunk) with webpack using `CommonsChunkPlugin` (if you’re using webpack < 4)

```
entry: {
  vendor: [
    'angular',
    'jquery',
    // etc.
  ],
  app: './index.js'
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',   
    minChunks: Infinity,
  })
]
```

---

You can also use `DllPlugin` for this, and [there’s an example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/explicit-vendor-chunk).